# "PDOException: could not find driver" inside docker container where PDO modules exist

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, pdo, fpm

I want to run php-fpm in a docker container, but get an error message after starting the container:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver.

I use php7.4 with event engine and a postgres database in a separate container (I use docker-compose to start them all) and are working on ubuntu20.04.

**The weird thing is: My collegues installed the same stuff without having this error, so the error cannot come from an incorrect docker file.**

What I tried so far:

- I can connect to the database with psql from the shell.
- I printed out all modules that are loaded in the container, and they include `pdo` and `pdo_pgsql`.

The error refers to this method:

```
    public function pdoConnection(): PDO
    {
        /** @var PDO $pdo */
        $pdo = $this->makeSingleton(PDO::class, function () {
            $this->assertMandatoryConfigExists('pdo.dsn');
            $this->assertMandatoryConfigExists('pdo.user');
            $this->assertMandatoryConfigExists('pdo.pwd');

            return new PDO(
                $this->config()->stringValue('pdo.dsn'),
                $this->config()->stringValue('pdo.user'),
                $this->config()->stringValue('pdo.pwd'),
                [

                    // the next line is the line the error message refers to
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,

                    // This is necessary due to the way pgBouncer handles (or not handles) prepared statements.
                    // See https://www.pgbouncer.org/faq.html#how-to-use-prepared-statements-with-transaction-pooling
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
                ]
            );
        });

        return $pdo;
    }
```

I checked `pdo.dns`, `pdo.user` and `pdo.pwd`, they are all correct. I defined DNS via

```
DNS = "pgsql:host=HOSTNAME port=5432 dbname=DATABASENAME"
```

The docker file includes

```
docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the DNS string, the quotation marks are wrong. It works with this:

```
DNS = pgsql:host=HOSTNAME;port=5432;dbname=DATABASENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

In your docker file try to add code below:

```
docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_pgsql
```

Hope help you.

Comment: This is already present in the docker file

Comment: @Julia Could you please to show your dockerfile?